# google spreadsheets: compare two cells and pull out different words

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have two cells that contain the concatenated column values separated by the | symbol. I want, without using a script, write a formula that compares these two cells and shows different words. Words that were used in A2 cell, but were not used in A1.

For example:

in cell A1 I have

test1 | banana | test2 | cat,

and in A2 cell i have

test1 | pineapple | test2 | dog.

The result of the formula should be something like

pineapple | dog

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({SPLIT(A2," | ");COUNTIF(SPLIT(A1," | "),SPLIT(A2," | "))}),"select Col1 where Col2=0",0))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=TRIM(JOIN("|"; FILTER(SPLIT(A2; "|"); 
 NOT(COUNTIF(SPLIT(A2; "|"); SPLIT(A1; "|"))))))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I will also keep it for myself